# Language detection in PHP ( UTF-8 )

Tags: php, internationalization

What code snippets are out there for detecting the language of a chunk of UTF-8 text? I basically need to filter a large amount of spam that happens to be in Chinese and Arabic. There's a PECL extension for that, but I want to do this purely in PHP code. I guess I need to loop through a Unicode string with a unicode version of ord() and then create some kind of a range table for different languages.

Comment: Note that you can't really find out the language without a lot of in-depth analysis that probably goes way over what you want to do. Finding out the script 'though might proof much easier and is probably sufficient.

Comment: @saua: yes you can.  Google's done the work for you.  See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Pipe your text through [Google's language detection](http://www.google.com/uds/samples/language/detect.html).  You can do this via AJAX.  Here is the [documentation/developer's guide](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/).  For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("language", "1");

    function initialize() {
      var text = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
      google.language.detect(text, function(result) {
        if (!result.error && result.language) {
          google.language.translate(text, result.language, "en",
                                    function(result) {
            var translated = document.getElementById("translation");
            if (result.translation) {
              translated.innerHTML = result.translation;
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="text">你好，很高興見到你。</div>
    <div id="translation"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could translate the UTF-8 string into its Unicode code points and look for “suspicious ranges”.

```
function utf8ToUnicode($utf8)
{
    if (!is_string($utf8)) {
        return false;
    }
    $unicode  = array();
    $mbbytes  = array();
    $mblength = 1;
    $strlen   = strlen($utf8);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $strlen; $i++) {
        $byte = ord($utf8{$i});
        if ($byte < 128) {
            $unicode[] = $byte;
        } else {
            if (count($mbbytes) == 0) {
                $mblength = ($byte < 224) ? 2 : 3;
            }
            $mbbytes[] = $byte;
            if (count($mbbytes) == $mblength) {
                if ($mblength == 3) {
                    $unicode[] = ($mbbytes[0] & 15) * 4096 + ($mbbytes[1] & 63) * 64 + ($mbbytes[2] & 63);
                } else {
                    $unicode[] = ($mbbytes[0] & 31) * 64 + ($mbbytes[1] & 63);
                }
                $mbbytes = array();
                $mblength = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return $unicode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is probably to have a dictionary of common words in different languages and then test how many positive matches you get against each language. It's a rather costly (computation-wise) task though.

Comment: It does not have to be words, just single characters in a certain range are enough to identify Arabic and Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

**Arabic characters** are mainly in **Unicode range** [0600–06FF](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf). Unicode has a few supplements etc. for Arabic. For example, the [code range 0750–077F](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0750.pdf) contains mainly Arabic characters that are used primarily in some African languages. The [code range 08A0–08FF](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U08A0.pdf) cover some more letters for African languages, for European and Central Asian
languages, Pakistani Quranic marks, etc. The two other Unicode code ranges for Arabic, [FB50–FDFF](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFB50.pdf) and [FE70–FEFF](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFE70.pdf) are probably less important if you already cover 0600–06FF.

Characters for **Chinese** (and Japanese and Korean) are registered in a different Unicode range (with several exentsions). The most important one is [4E00–9FD5](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U4E00.pdf). Assuming you don't need to worry about Japanese, this should be sufficient for *script detection*, but if you want to check the extensions, check the Unicode Consortium's [list of code charts](http://unicode.org/charts/).

So if you need to **filter only Arabic and Chinese scripts** and don't want to use the approach suggested by troelskn (i.e. using lists of common words for the languages that you want to identify - this does not scale too well for a large number of languages), detecting the code range of the characters in your input should be sufficient. StackOverflow has already solved an earlier question about [**how to detect Unicode ranges in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713443/detect-unicode-character-range-in-php#20714508).