# Detect Unicode Character Range in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

Evening,

Does anyone have an idea what the quickest way to detect the Unicode range of a string is in PHP? I thought there would be something to do this in PHP, but I can't find anything. Ideally what I want is a function that will say, 100% of 'John Jones' is Latin OR 'Jones језик' is 50% Latin and 50% Cyrillic.

You could do it with something like the below in ReEx:

```
strA = 'John Jones';
$strB = 'Српски језик';
$strC = 'Հայաստանի Հանրապետություն';
preg_match( '~[\p{Cyrillic}\p{Common}]+~u', $strB, $res );
```

But this will require checking against each range, which does not seem a good idea. Alternatively, you could get the unicode value of each character and check which range it is in. But I'd imagine someone has already made something like this.

**EDIT**

To give a little more idea on why this may be useful, as pointed out in the comments, some people sometimes mix the visually identical Latin and Cyrillic characters. e.g. this is a search for Croatia with a Cyrillic 'С' and the rest in Latin:

https://www.google.am/search?q=%22%D0%A1roatia%22&aq=f&oq=%22%D0%A1roatia%22

Search again with full-Latin and you will get about 100,000,000 results instead of 20,000. In such cases it would be desirable to replace characters as is appropriate in the context of the text. A good example of where such detection is useful is people who use Cyrillic letter to bypass profanity filters.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve that makes you think you need to known which percentage of characters is from which unicode script block? for instance, knowing that 80% of the characters are from Latin and 20% from Latin Extended A won't tell you if it's Romanian, or Vietnamese.

Comment: Hi,

I've got a table of human names. Some of these are in various non-Latin characters and some are mixed. I need to detect which are which, as many alphabets, such as Cyrillic can be transliterated, but others, such as Arabic can't, or at least not meaningfully. Further in the case of people from Eastern Europe, Russia etc. they sometimes use Cyrillic characters that look exactly the same as Latin ones or vice-versa, leading to mixed string. I'm converting all names to Latin, and I need the above data, so I can know what to do to convert each name to Latin.

Comment: Why? just store UTF8 without converting to latin. It's 2013, virtually all common technologies support it.

Comment: I'm working on a study of names throughout the world. The study is based on the Latin rendering of names. I need to convert all non-Latin names, so they can be considered for the study.

Comment: in that case I wish you luck. romanisation is highly ambiguous (dmitry? dumitru? demitriev?) and I know of no things that can help autoromanise names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked on something. This will detect the range of each character. I've only put Armenian, Latin and Russian in to start with. If anyone else has need for this, you'll need to find the character ranges to the detectRanges function from a source like: http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/ I'd like to see if there is a better way of doing that part. Make sure any alphabetic character in the ranges are lower case.

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
echo header( "Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8", true );

class DetectUnicodeRanges
{
    function entityToUTF8( $number )
    {
        if( $number < 0 )
                return false;

        # Replace ASCII characters
        if( $number < 128 )
                return chr( $number );

        # Replace illegal Windows characters
        if( $number < 160 )
        {
            switch( $number )
            {
                case 128: $conversion = 8364; break;
                case 129: $conversion = 160; break;
                case 130: $conversion = 8218; break;
                case 131: $conversion = 402; break;
                case 132: $conversion = 8222; break;
                case 133: $conversion = 8230; break;
                case 134: $conversion = 8224; break;
                case 135: $conversion = 8225; break;
                case 136: $conversion = 710; break;
                case 137: $conversion = 8240; break;
                case 138: $conversion = 352; break;
                case 139: $conversion = 8249; break;
                case 140: $conversion = 338; break;
                case 141: $conversion = 160; break;
                case 142: $conversion = 381; break;
                case 143: $conversion = 160; break;
                case 144: $conversion = 160; break;
                case 145: $conversion = 8216; break;
                case 146: $conversion = 8217; break;
                case 147: $conversion = 8220; break;
                case 148: $conversion = 8221; break;
                case 149: $conversion = 8226; break;
                case 150: $conversion = 8211; break;
                case 151: $conversion = 8212; break;
                case 152: $conversion = 732; break;
                case 153: $conversion = 8482; break;
                case 154: $conversion = 353; break;
                case 155: $conversion = 8250; break;
                case 156: $conversion = 339; break;
                case 157: $conversion = 160; break;
                case 158: $conversion = 382; break;
                case 159: $conversion = 376; break;
            }

            return $conversion;
        }

        if ( $number < 2048 )
                return chr( ($number >> 6 ) + 192 ) . chr( ( $number & 63 ) + 128 );
        if ( $number < 65536 )
                return chr( ( $number >> 12 ) + 224 ) . chr( ( ( $number >> 6 ) & 63 ) + 128 ) . chr( ( $number & 63 ) + 128 );
        if ( $number < 2097152 )
                return chr( ( $number >> 18 ) + 240 ) . chr( ( ( $number >> 12 ) & 63 ) + 128 ) . chr( ( ( $number >> 6 ) & 63 ) + 128 ) . chr( ( $number & 63 ) + 128 );

        return false;
    }

    function MBStrToHexes( $str )
    {        
        $str = mb_convert_encoding( $str, 'UCS-4BE' );
        $hexs = array();
        for( $i = 0; $i < mb_strlen( $str, 'UCS-4BE' ); $i++ )
        {        
            $s2 = mb_substr( $str, $i, 1, 'UCS-4BE' );                    
            $val = unpack( 'N', $s2 );
            $hexs[] = str_pad( dechex( $val[1] ), 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT );                
        }        
        return( $hexs );
    }

    function detectRanges( $str )
    {
        $hexes = $this->MBStrToHexes( $str );
        foreach( $hexes as $hex )
        {
            if( ( $hex >= '0041' ) && ( $hex <= '024f' ) )
                echo $this->entityToUTF8( hexdec($hex) ) . ' - Latin<br />';
            elseif( ( $hex >= '0400' ) && ( $hex <= '04ff' ) )
                echo $this->entityToUTF8( hexdec($hex) ) . ' - Cyrillic<br />';
            elseif( ( $hex >= '0530' ) && ( $hex <= '058f' ) )
                echo $this->entityToUTF8( hexdec($hex) ) . ' - Armenian<br />';
            else
                echo $this->entityToUTF8( $hex ) . ' - Some Other Range<br />';
        }
    }

}

#$strB = 'Cornelius Trow';
$strB = 'Cornelius Српски Հայաստանի';
#$strB = 'Հայաստանի Հանրապետություն';
echo 'Testing String: ' . $strB . '<br />';
$dur = new DetectUnicodeRanges();
$dur->detectRanges( $strB );
```